# Looking for a well-known refrain or proverb indicating that some big trouble has just started

Tags: translation, popular-refrains, literature, proverb-requests, spanish

I am translating into English a famous refrain from Spanish, [*Ahí fue Troya*](http://dicci-eponimos.blogspot.com/2009/11/ahi-o-alli-o-aqui-fue-troya.html).  That means something like *Then a big trouble started.*

I am looking for some correspondingly recognizable refrain I can use in English for the translation. Because this is a work of literature, having a polished style and wording is very important.

Comment: Quoth Ozymandias, “There goes the neighborhood!” :)

Comment: Interesting question. Can you give a bit more info on the context of usage for your translaton?

Comment: Oh, we got trouble,
Right here in River City!
With a capital "T"
And that rhymes with "P"
And that stands for pool

Comment: @SConroy I am translating a short story of my e-book "Hacia el ruido y la lluvia" https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/290273, the original phrase is: "Pero vieras, «ahí fue Troya», como diría mi abuelo –agregó él–"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what kind of trouble it is, you could say:

> Then all hell broke loose

That implies that the trouble that started was chaotic or disruptive.

If things just started going badly, you would say:

> Then everything went to hell

or

> Then it all fell apart

Comment: I like this answer as it provides several options. I like the first option a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**then the shit hit the fan.**

Oxford English Dictionary:

> a.  orig. U.S. Military. (when) the shit hits the fan: (when) a
>   situation suddenly becomes critical; (when) trouble suddenly or
>   rapidly breaks out.

Not as elegant as a classical reference but even people who have never heard it will understand what sort of situation would ensue.

Answer (score 0):

"Then a big trouble started"--

One possibility, since you want something literary, is "The center was not holding."  This phrase resonates with W.B. Yates's poem "The Second Coming" [https://owlcation.com/humanities/Summary-and-Analysis-of-Poem-The-Second-Coming-].  The poem is about the rise of Nazi socialism in Europe.  "The Center Cannot Hold" has been used frequently as a book title.

The phrase "the shit hit the fan" would be appropriate only in a locker-room atmosphere or a bar, not in a literary work.